# QT: two layouts add the same widget

Tags: qt, layout, widget, hide

In Qt: I create a widget-ui class, and I want to make the widget appear in two different layouts in two separate base widget(or window). So I want to:

```
widget_based_class* inside = new widget_based_class(base_widget1);

QHBoxLayout *lay1=new QHBoxLayout(base_widget1);
base_widget->setLayout(lay1);
lay1->addWidget(inside);
base_widget1.show();

-------------------------------
base_widget1.hide();
QHBoxLayout *lay2=new QHBoxLayout(base_widget2);
base_widget->setLayout(lay2);
lay2->addWidget(inside);
base_widget2.show();
```

How cound I achieve this? (My program is more complicated, and I didn't see the code work.)
Tank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A QWidget has only one parent widget and only one geometry (position and size) in that parent. Every call of QLayout::addWidget() will reparent that widget to the widget, the layout is installed on.

Your second call of setLayout won't work as expected, because you have to delete the the existing layout manager before setting the new one:

```
delete base_widget->layout();
base_widget->setLayout(lay2);
```

If base_widget hasn't already got a layout manager, the layout manager lay2 would simply be reparented.

Answer (score 0):

If the widget will never be displayed twice on the screen, I don't see why you can't reparent it by addWidget/removeWidget.

In the OP, the parent widget/window is always hidden before the other one is shown. `addWidget` is called on the fly. We should also call `removeWidget` on the fly. It should be possible to move the widget around.

```
widget_based_class* inside = new widget_based_class(base_widget1);

QHBoxLayout *lay1=new QHBoxLayout(base_widget1);
base_widget->setLayout(lay1);
lay2->removeWidget(inside); // remove widget from other layout
lay1->addWidget(inside);    // add widget to this layout
base_widget1.show();

-------------------------------
base_widget1.hide();
QHBoxLayout *lay2=new QHBoxLayout(base_widget2);
base_widget->setLayout(lay2);
lay1->removeWidget(inside); //remove widget from other layout
lay2->addWidget(inside);    // add widget to this layout
base_widget2.show();
```

Answer (score -2):

Make one widget and use a pointer in each layout?

Comment: I think the effect of re-parenting should happen this way also.